# Aligning element within a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having issues aligning the dollar amounts (columns 2,3,4,5, & 6) with it its specified data label (pay total and extra in the first column). Also, I am using Bootstrap 3, on mobile view Pay total and Extra will stack underneath the interest rate. The dollar amount should also line up with the proper label. Can this be done with the current structure that I have? or do I have to re-structure it differently. [Here](https://codepen.io/carlosNavient/pen/rpqQEj) is the codepen:

```css
td,
th {
  border: solid;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%; 
}

th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 31%;
}
th:nth-child(2),
th:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(4),
th:nth-child(5),
th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Testing 0</th>
        <th>
          <input type="radio" name="allocation" value="highestInterestRate">
          <br> Testing <br> 1
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="radio" name="allocation" value="highestCurrentBalance">
          <br> Testing <br> # <br> 2
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="radio" name="allocation" value="lowestCurrentBalance">
          <br> Testing <br> 3
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="radio" name="allocation" value="prorate">
          <br> Testing <br> # <br> # <br> 4
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="radio" name="allocation" value="unsubsidizedLoans">
          <br> Testing <br> 5
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
                <p class="payment-loan-name"><strong>#1</strong> Hello this is name 1</p>
                <p>Current Balance $ 2,000.00</p>
                <p>Interest Rate 1.99%</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                <p>Pay total</p>
                <p>Extra</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <p>$ 200.00</p>
                </div>
              </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>$ 200.00</p>
                <p>$ 100.00</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>$ 200.00
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>$ 200.00</p>
                <p>$ 33.33</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>$ 200.00</p>
                <p>$ 50.00</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
                <p class="payment-loan-name"><strong>#2</strong> Hello this is name 2 and this is going to be in two lines</p>
                <p>Current Balance $ 2,000.00</p>
                <p>Interest Rate 1.99%</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                <p>Pay total</p>
                <p>Extra</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                $ 100.00
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>$ 100.00</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                $ 100.00
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>$ 100.00</p>
                <p>$ 50.00</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>$ 300.00</p>
                <p>$ 50.00</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: This can be properly done with a table structure then do col-span and row-span where necessary. With those attributes, you can achieve anything the way you want it to look like

Comment: So the proper thing to do is to desgin the table like you will normally do, each data in a <tr> and then <td>, then join rows where necessary

Comment: Show a picture output of your requirement.

Comment: I would suggest CSS Grid and Flexbox for this kind of thing. It will still remain responsive which is what you want from Bootstrap anyways

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated this in my own [Codepen](https://codepen.io/akinhwan/pen/eyPwRm?editors=1100)

I refactored it with simple divs, without bootstrap classes, using CSS Grid.

```
  .header{
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 1fr;
     grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
```

The above code defines the number of rows and columns, fr is simply a fractional unit.

```
.number-two{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

The nice thing is you can define another grid within a grid! So I do that with the rather complex cell that you have with two columns and three rows. And apply the same layout to the other cells in the row so that the values align. Normally you have to define which `grid-row: x` or `grid-column: y` that the values belong in, but CSS Grid will automatically position children elements of the defined grid if left undefined.

More details here [MDN CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)